# how do I foreach through html input form and insert multiple rows or one based on a selected date field?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-into

how do I foreach through html input form and insert multiple rows or one based on a selected date field? in other words when a user enters "name" "description" and "shift" and then selects either one date or more then one. PHP will then enter the same information for either one new row or multiples based on how many dates were selected.

```
<?php

 if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("| ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['description']);
$shift = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['shift']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['daterange']);


$sql = "insert into db (name,description,shift,evdate) values ('$name',              '   $desc','$shift','$date')";
$sql2 = "insert into db (name,description,shift,evdate) values ('$name', '                    '$desc','$shift','$insert')";

if ($date=0) {
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

}else{
    $daterange = explode(',',$date);
    foreach($daterange as $insert) {    
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);

 }
 }



 if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
 echo "";
  } else{
  echo "| ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
  }

 if ($link->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "It Worked..... Maybe!!!!!!";
  } else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
   }
   }
   $link->close();
    ?>
    <form action="test_insert.php" method="post">

<div class="col col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0">
<div class="form-group col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-12">
    <label for="Name">Employee Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" id="name"           required>
    <p class="help-block col-lg-12">First and Last Name Please.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" id="description"       placeholder="description..." required>
   <p class="help-block">For Example: "Vacation Full Day" or "PTO 2 Hours."      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-3">
    <label for="shift">Shift:</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="shift" value="First Shift" id="shift" checked> First Shift |
    <input type="radio" name="shift" value="Second Shift" id="shift"> Second  Shift |
    <input type="radio" name="shift" value="Third Shift" id="shift"> Third Shift
    <p class="help-block">Select Correct Shift Worked.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-3">
   <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
   <label for="date2">Date/Dates:</label>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="daterange" placeholder="Select  Your Date"  />    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
     <label for="date2">Date/Dates:</label>
     <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="daterange" placeholder="Select Your Date"  />    
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
      <label for="date2">Date/Dates:</label>
       <input type="text" id="datepicker3" name="daterange" placeholder="Select Your Date"  />  
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
       <label for="date2">Date/Dates:</label>
       <input type="text" id="datepicker4" name="daterange" placeholder="Select Your Date"  />  
        </div>
       <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
        <label for="date2">Date/Dates:</label>
         <input type="text" id="datepicker5" name="daterange" placeholder="Select Your Date"  />    
       </div>


     <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class= "btn btn-primary"> 
      </div>
      </div>

       </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think the best way is to use AJAX,

Then with the response as a string you make a table or foreach in php as a string and then use the .html adapter to output the newly made data.

```
function submitForm(form){
var url = form.attr("action");
var formData = {};
$(form).find("input[name]").each(function (index, node) {
    formData[node.name] = node.value;
});
$.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
      $('#showresults').html(result);
});
```

}

Comment: where does this fit into my code, I'm sorry this is new for me and I need a bit more explanation...

Comment: Hi Adam, make a new php file. url to this file. Then echo the result as a string which you foreach the string of text depending on what the drop down is selected.

They do this here but use a different call other than ajax : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: that I can work with! thank you for your time and good advice!